# Deallocate dynamic array returned from a function

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
string *myFunction(void);

int main(void)
{
    string *newArrPtr = myFunction(void);

    //Do something with array

    //Deallocate memory here?
    //delete[] newArrPtr? 
    //newArrPtr = NULL? 

    return 0;
}

string *myFunction(void)
{
    string *oldArrPtr = new string[256];

    //Do something with array

    return oldArrPtr;

    //Deallocate memory here?
    //delete[] oldArrPtr? 
    //oldArrPtr = NULL? 
}
```

As you can see, I'm making a new dynamically allocated array in `myFunction`, but I'm now sure how and when to deallocate it again. And if someone can tell my why?

Comment: I would recommend `RAII`. You create a class , allocate memory at the constructor and deallocate on the destructor

Comment: Each `new[]` should be matched by a `delete[]`. It doesn't matter when or where you do the `new[]` or the `delete[]`.

Comment: Deallocate it only after you have finished using it. In your case that would be in `main`. In real code you would use a `vector<string>` instead of dynamic allocation.

Comment: With that said, unless it's an assignment requirement to use pointers, I recommend either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (if the size is known at compile-time) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of manual and explicit memory handling.

Comment: I assume this I some sort of exercise? It's probably getting at the fact you can't do anything after a `return` statement. So you should presumably deallocate the string after it's usefulness has run its course. Having said that it looks like you've typedef'd `char*` to `string`, I would recommend never doing that no matter what your teacher says, it's outright wrong.

Comment: If you know the number of strings will be 256, then simply create a `struct MyArray { std::string sArray[256]; };` and return / pass that around.  No dynamic allocation, no pointers needed, and if commanded to by your teacher, doesn't use STL or vectors.  The only thing to remember is that to access the internal array, you use something like `myArray.sArray[x];` instead of simply `sArray[x];`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all of your brilliant answers and suggestions. I've never thought about using vectors, and it is so much easier (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I'm now sure how and when to deallocate it again.

"How" is easy: you just use `delete` or `delete[]` when dealing with arrays. "When" is more interesting. You cannot use `delete[]` inside `myFunction` because you would free memory before returning it. *Side note:* inside a function, no code gets executed after `return` statement, if that was your intention.

So the problem is that your `myFunction` allocates memory but it should not free it. You could of course use `delete[]` outside of `myFunction`, in `main` in your case. But this is a bad design: some function returns a pointer. You get that pointer but there is no way for you to know who is responsible for deallocation. Is it you? Is it `myFunction` or some other function? Or maybe the pointer points to some piece of memory that is not supposed to be deallocated at all? And also, are you supposed to use `delete` or `delete[]`? The function doesn't give you any hint about what kind of pointer it returns. This design forces you to either fully understand what `myFunction` does or to properly document its behaviour. Additionally any changes to `myFunction` are now hard and it is way to easy to introduce backwards incompatible (potentially hard to detect) changes. And all of simply because `std::string*` means too many things.

C++ solves this issue by introducing [std::unique_ptr<std::string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr<std::string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Utilize one of them instead of raw pointer, when dealing with a single object. When dealing with arrays, I advice using [std::vector<std::string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). That way the situation is clear and as a bonus you don't have to use `delete/delete[]` at all (although you may be forced to use [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) instead). Another bonus (thanks to @JorgeBellon) is that with smart pointers/vectors you are exception safe.

Comment: As a bonus point, if `Do something with array` throws an exception that you did not expect, smart pointers and `vector` will release the memory for you, where using `delete[]` would otherwise result in a memory leak.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, freakish. Really detailed and i'm going to use vectors (y)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a new (respectively new[]), you should have a matching delete (respectively delete[]), but when it's not very obvious to know when your object can be deallocated, the simplest solution is to use the modern shared pointers, your object is allocated dynamically but it is deleted automatically when it's not referenced and not used anymore, which means you don't have to delete it manually. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string[]> arrPtr(new std::string[256]);

    arrPtr[0] = "Hello";
    std::cout << arrPtr[0];

    // No need to use delete[] !

    // You need c++17 to use shared_ptr with dynamic arrays
    // You can also use std::array or std::vector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
string *myFunction(void);

int main(void)
{
    string *newArrPtr = myFunction(void);

    //Do something with array

    //Deallocate memory here?
    delete[] newArrPtr? 
    newArrPtr = NULL? 

    return 0;
}

string *myFunction(void)
{
    string *oldArrPtr = new string[256];

    //Do something with array

    return oldArrPtr;
}
```

I think this code would be work.
But it's not a good habit to write the code that is readable and manageable easily.